# SHA256 possible to multithread to increase speed?

Tags: c#, multithreading, encryption, hash

```
using (FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(path))
{
    SHA256Managed sha = new SHA256Managed();
    byte[] hash = sha.ComputeHash(stream);
    return RSAEncrypt.GenerateDigitalSignature(hash,privateKey);
}
```

My hashing method to create a hash is it possible to split the file into smaller parts use a buffer and glue the result back into one single hash? I am asking this because hashing large files ( +-1gb) can take up to 20 seconds to complete running on a separate thread. Is it even possible to multithread it the way I described?

Comment: Interesting possibility here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33196209/parallel-hash-computing-via-multiple-transformblocks-results-in-a-disarray. Just keep in mind, hashing is *meant* to be slow. If you can hash fast, what's the difference btw that and a rainbow table? And then, when you find out that your file is decrptyable in 7 seconds or less, how will you feel then?

Comment: @code4life Hashing is **not** meant to be slow. Some uses such as password hashing needs to take time and that is accomplished with iterations. Hashing a file needs to be as fast as possible. My silly iPhone runs SHA-256 at around 1GB/s.

Comment: @code4life So the answer is no, you can't use multithreading with sha256 :(?

Comment: Does this need to be a SHA256 or could it be something else?

Comment: needs to be sha256 but feel to give your suggestion

Comment: Are you sure the hashing is the bottleneck? It looks you have IO problem

Comment: @Mercenary_Frank: baed on what the other post was saying, it's theoretically possible, but requires a deeper understanding of how the hash is composed. The tl;dr == it's not trivial code.

Comment: @code4life actually that other post says the same thing: there is no multithreaded algorithm for common hashes like md5 sha1,256,512... The answer suggests to use another algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this needs to be SHA256 and nothing else then there is nothing you can do.

If you can decide the hash you can use a Merkle Tree construction. Two Merkle levels are enough to max out your CPUs. It would be easy to implement.

A Merke hash based on SHA256 does *not* result in SHA256 output.

Comment: This is a condensed version of the answer given by Maarten Bodewes on the linked question (linked by code4life). Why not vote to close a duplicate?

Comment: @ArtjomB. the question is not a duplicate although the answer answers both.

Comment: The answer is multithreading isn't possible, use a Merkle Tree.

Comment: @Mercenary_Frank what do you mean by that? I agree but I wonder why you said that. Do you disagree with something? Also note, that a Merkle tree does *not* give you SHA256 ever which is a requirement of yours.